# Binomial series in $x=-1$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

The binomial series is $$(1+x)^\alpha= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} \ x^k$$
And $$ \binom{\alpha}{k} = \dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2) \cdots (\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$$
I have to prove that if $x=-1$, the series converges for $\alpha \geq 0$ and diverges for $\alpha <0$

I'm confused, because if $x=-1$ we have
$$0 =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} \ (-1)^k$$ and I don't know how to continue with the proof

Comment: You didn’t say anything about restrictions on $x$. Generally, when $\alpha$ is not a positive integer, convergence of the series requires $|x|<1$. Your statement about exponents $\alpha$ would seem to require $\alpha\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, it's necessary that $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Notice that the left-hand side when $x=-1$ and $\alpha=-3$ is technically undefined (since $0^{-3}=\frac{1}{0^3}=\frac{1}{0}$.

Comment: You might think about the Divergence Theorem and what it implies when $\alpha < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha$ is restricted to the integers, when $\alpha<0$ and $x=-1$ then every term in the series is positive and all are greater than ro equal to one, so the series diverges.  When $\alpha \geqslant 0$ then for $k > \alpha$ each coefficient, $$\left( \alpha \atop k\right) = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$$ is zero because once $k > \alpha$ there is a zero factor in every coefficient.  Thus the terms in the series are all zero for sufficiently large $k$ and the series converges for all values of $x$ - in this case it is obviously just a finite order polynomial.